# How write notation for a subitem as root element for JSon Embarcadero rest debugger

Tags: json, rest, debugging, element, root

I need make a subitem (that isn´t the root element) as the root element from a json object.
See picture.

[image: Embarcadero rest debugger]

```
I need the subnode "Lista" to be the root node, how notate?
result/Lista fails
result:Lista fails
result\Lista fails
result:/Lista fails
result:[Lista] fails
result:{Lista} fails....
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!!
result[0].Lista is the correct notation!!